# React&Redux auto rerender with loosing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I learning react and redux and have an issue: 
my app renders okay with my initial state but after some very little time <1s it for some reason rerenders without state. 
 : [Here is video where i show my issue (i cleared my console before reloading the page)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N0SPbqq5bk&feature=youtu.be)

Here is some of my code (without imports):

```
     const initialStore = {
            recipeList:[
                {id: 0, name: "Sufle", ingredients: ["kartoshka", "shepki", "seledka"]},
                {id: 1, name: "Borsch", ingredients: ["capusta", "blood", "corpse"]},
                {id: 2, name: "Fufel", ingredients: ["leg", "owl's head", "puke"]}
            ]
        }

        let store = createStore(reducer, initialStore);

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <RecipeBox/>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById("root")
    )
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    MY REDUCER:

```
    export default (state = [], action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'ADD_RECIPE':
                return [
                    ...state.recipes,
                    { name: action.name, ingredients: action.ingredients, id: action.id }
                ]
            case 'EDIT_RECIPE':
                return [
                    state.recipes.map((recipe) => {
                        if (recipe.id === action.id) {
                            return { name: action.name, ingredients: action.ingredients }
                        }
                        return recipe;
                    })
                ]
            case 'DELETE_RECIPE':
                return state.recipes.filter((recipe) => {
                    return recipe.id !== action.id;
                })
            default:
                return state;
        }
    };
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    RECIPEBOX.JS

```
    class RecipeBox extends Component {
        state = {  }
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Recipes/>
                    <button>Add recipe</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    RECIPES.JS

```
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        console.log(state);  // From here i see that my component renders 2 times
               //this is what you see in my console
        return {recipes: state.recipeList}
    }

    const Recipes = connect(
        mapStateToProps
    )(RecipeList);
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
RecipeList.js

```
const RecipeList = (props) => {
    // console.log(props.recipes); // first render is okay, after rerender = //undefined
    return (
        <ul>
            {props.recipes.map((recipe) =>
                <Recipe
                    className="recipe"
                    name={recipe.name}
                    ingredients={recipe.ingredients}
                    id={recipe.id}
                    key={recipe.id}
                />
            )}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Recipe.js

```
const Recipe = (props) => {
    let ingredients = [], temp;
    ingredients = props.ingredients.map((ingred, index) => {
        temp = <li className = "ingredient" key={index}>{ingred}</li>;
        return temp;
    })
    return (
        <li>
            <h3>{props.name}</h3>
            <div className="ingredients">
                <h3>Ingredients</h3>
                <ul>
                    {ingredients}
                </ul>
                <button>Delete</button>
                <button>Edit</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
}
```

Comment: Try installing the [redux devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/).  It helps a *ton* with these kinds of errors.

Comment: You can also just log state and action in your reducer.  Something like this: `console.warn(action, state)` on the first line of the reducer function is almost as good as the devtools.

Comment: i have redux devtools chrome extension but it seems doesn't show much to me, should i use devtools from gaearon?

Comment: @BonsaiOak That is what i've got by console.warn(action, state)  [first render](http://radikal.ru/big/lmysjdpv2ypum),,,,   [autorender](http://radikal.ru/big/rdzirioces911)

Comment: The chrome extension is much more convenient then bundling it into your app.  Just make sure you're following the instructions to set it up.

Comment: @BonsaiOak funFact: today it's just works without changing anything... How is that possible? Yesterday i restarted my webpack server but it wasn't help, so computer restart actually fixed my problem but how?)